# SSIS : Error while passing the webservice object from one script task to another

Tags: ssis

I have two script tasks that reference a webservice. Both the script tasks are referncing to the same webservice. Once I have created the instance of the webservice and established my
connection , i want to pass the same instance to the next script task as I need to make another webservice call.

To achieve that in my first task , I do the following

1. Create a package level variable IPSService of the type object
2. Create a webservice reference
3. Add the using statement that is using ST_d4beade8c14e45c3af4e582df4c22c89.csproj.uk.co.iress.webservices; (Got the reference from the object browser)
4. Create in the instance of the service in the script task
5. Assign the object to  Dts.Variables["User::IPSService"].Value = iPSService;
6. Set the ReadWrite variables in the script properties to User::IPSService.

In Second script task , I do the following

1. Set the readonly variable property of the script task to User::IPSService
2. Create a webservice reference
3. Add the using statement that is using ST_d4beade8c14e45c3af4e582df4c22c89.csproj.uk.co.iress.webservices; (Got the reference from the object browser)
4. In the main method ,  IPSService iPSService1 = (IPSService)Dts.Variables["User::IPSService"].Value;

However when i run the tasks , I get the following error

Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ST_d4beade8c14e45c3af4e582df4c22c89.csproj.uk.co.iress.webservices.IPSService' to type 'ST_d4beade8c14e45c3af4e582df4c22c89.csproj.uk.co.iress.webservices.IPSService'.
   at ST_d4beade8c14e45c3af4e582df4c22c89.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()

I just did a small change to avoid passing the object and recreate the object in the second script method but i get a new error Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Invalid SDO Topic TD_ERROR.

Can anybody tell me what the problem is

Comment: Can you explain this line `Dts.Variables["User::IPSService"].Value = iPSService` what's the value of `iPSService` ? and it's better to add some picture to have more visiblity of your problem

Comment: its a class of the webservice with the help of which you can access the webservice method. So I am basically creating an object of it to access the webservice methods. I am able to access the webservice method in the first script task. The problem happens when i try to pass this object to second script task.

Comment: @Tom what was your fix? I'm currently having the same issue trying to covert IOSPlus session create to IRESS, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed. There were some header information that was missed while making a call to the webservice.