# SSIS - Control flow issue

Tags: ssis

Hi I have script task on  the control flow. This would call a webservice and establish a session.  Then a another script task to call the webservice and close the session. In between the two script tasks I need to fetch data from database and upload data calling a webservice. I have thought of using a data flow task for fetching the data and then creating a script task on the control flow to upload the data. I need to pass the session information from script task to dataflow task and dataflow task to script upload task. I would also need to pass the data from dataflow task to the script task. Could you let me know how it could be done.

1. Script task on control flow to establish the session and get a sessionkey.
2. Create a dataflow task to fetch the data from the database. Pass the sessionkey to the dataflow task.
3. Create a script task on the control flow to call a webservice to upload the data from step 2. This task has to be looped. Also the data needs to be passed from dataflow task to script task 
   on the control flow. Session information needs to be passed as well from dataflow to script task.
4. Create a script task to call a webservice to close the session. Need to pass the session key from the previous task to this one.

Could somebody help ?

Comment: Just like in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503309/ssis-error-while-passing-the-webservice-object-from-one-script-task-to-another you save the session identifier into a SSIS variable (probably of type string) then use that SSIS variable in you script destination. Again I suggest that this is too complex for SSIS but good on you for sticking with it. Your first step is to load the session identifier into a global variable

Comment: You just need to dive in and try it and post specific issues. So first complete part 1 and save the result to a SSIS variable. There are many examples online and it seems from your other questions that you may have already achieved this.

Comment: Hi Nick. I have already finished the Srcipt task that calls a webservice to open and close session

Comment: You can use object variable in SSIS script task and can use that object variable in data flow task

Comment: That's good. In your script tasks are you saving the session id to a SSIS variable? Your next step is to drop on a dataflow and use an OLE DB source and a script destination. Your script destination can then use the session id in the variable